# Is it possible to run Jetty from a different JVM using run-forked?

Tags: java, maven, jetty

Maven is pointed to Java 6, I would like to run Jetty from a Java 7 JVM when invoking it from the jetty-maven-plugin, using the run-forked goal. I see an option for setting the jvmArgs, but I don't see anything that allows me to pick a different JVM.

I think I could just use maven-exec and drop down to a shell script (invoking whichever java binary I'd like), but I would rather live in maven-land if possible.

FYI, I'm using Maven 3, and Jetty 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.
[JettyRunForkedMojo](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/maven/plugin/JettyRunForkedMojo.html) uses standard JDK `ProcessBuilder.start()` to launch forked JVM.

As seen in [source](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/maven/plugin/JettyRunForkedMojo.java?h=jetty-9.2.x), Mojo uses [getJavaBin() method](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/maven/plugin/JettyRunForkedMojo.java?h=jetty-9.2.x#n740) to find path to java executable.
Value of system variable "java.home" is analyzed for that.

So, with this config for jetty-maven-plugin:

```
...
<execution>
    <id>start-jetty</id>
    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>run-forked</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        ...
        <systemProperties>
            <force>true</force> <!-- !!! important -->
            <systemProperty>
                <name>java.home</name>
                <value>/usr/lib/jvm/j2sdk1.6-oracle/</value>
            </systemProperty>
        </systemProperties>                   
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

one may launch forked JVM of specified version.

In my example, I have default java home set 1.7, but forcing forked JVM to use 1.6 JDK (also installed).

Answer (score 0):

Maven typically doesn't support alternate JVM behavior in any of its plugins.
You can instead choose to run in Java 7, and all of the compile / testing is done with a `-source` and `-target` of Java 6, leaving the jetty-maven-plugin at the same JVM level as what you executed the build as.

Jetty's own build does this.

We build in Java 8, with a `-source` and `-target` of Java 7.

You might also want to look into the enforcer plugin and setup a minimum JVM level enforcement for the build.